# Type Mismatch error: wordObj.Documents.Open(filename)

Tags: vba, ms-word

Correct me if I am wrong: I am attempting to open an document from an instance of the Word Application using the method "Open" and supplying it a string argument "filename" as shown in my code below.

If the error is type mismatch, then I am assuming it is referring to my argument type not being the correct variable type? Or is it something else?

```
Sub export_excel_to_word()
   Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
   Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open("\filepath\document.docx")
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you `Dim objDoc` as?

Comment: @BigBen I did not. I only define it as `Dim objDoc`

Comment: Have you perhaps oversimplified the example code? As posted it shouldn't throw a Type Mismatch.

Comment: No - The code is a snippet from larger code but still has the issue after extracting it. Perhaps its the filepath?

Comment: Are you concatenating or do you have an entire filepath within `""`?

Comment: Entire filepath within ""